# Solve $ \left( \log_2\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right) > 0 $

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithmic inequalities. How to solve this:

$$ \left( \log_2\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right) > 0 $$

Comment: Note that $\log_ab=c\iff a^c=b.$ Thus $\log_2 \dfrac{x-1}{x+2}>0 \iff \dfrac{x-1}{x+2}>1=2^0.$

Comment: This is the hint in previous comment: $\log_2 \dfrac{x-1}{x+2}>0$ implies $$\frac{x-1}{x+2}=2^{\log_2 \dfrac{x-1}{x+2}}>2^0=1.$$

Comment: You've a very good answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we note that $\log_ab=c\Longleftrightarrow a^c=b$

Therefore we can say that \begin{align}\log_2\frac{x-1}{x+2}&>0\\
\frac{x-1}{x+2}&>2^0\\
\frac{x-1}{x+2}&>1\end{align}

Now we can begin to solve this:

\begin{align}\frac{x-1}{x+2}&>1\\
\frac{x-1}{x+2}-1&>0\\
\frac{x-1}{x+2}-\frac{x+2}{x+2}&>0\\
\frac{x-1-x-2}{x+2}&>0\\
-\frac{3}{x+2}&>0\end{align}

We can't multiply both sides by $x+2$ as we may lose solutions, so we must turn to a [different approach](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/inequalities/rational/rational_inequalities.html).

First we find the undefined points by looking at the denominator - here the fraction is undefined when $x+2=0\Longleftrightarrow x=-2$

We then look either side of this point to determine the solution.

When $x=-3$, then we have $$-\frac{3}{-3+2}=\frac{-3}{-1}=3>0$$ and when $x=2$, then we have $$-\frac{3}{2+2}=-\frac34<0$$

Therefore we can conclude that the inequality holds when $$x<-2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\log _{ 2 } \left( \frac { x-1 }{ x+2 }  \right) >0\\ \log _{ 2 } \left( \frac { x-1 }{ x+2 }  \right) >\log _{ 2 } 1\\ \frac { x-1 }{ x+2 } >1\\ \frac { x-1 }{ x+2 } -1>0\\ \frac { x-1-x-2 }{ x+2 } >0\\ \frac { -3 }{ x+2 } >0\\ x+2<0\\ x<-2\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ $$

Comment: When a negative number is multiplied in both sides of inequality, the sign reverses; irrespective of the fact that 0 is in the RHS. Is this true?

Comment: @RaviPrakash,it is correct

Comment: How did you conclude that $$\frac{-3}{x+2}>0\Longleftrightarrow x+2<0$$? That line is probably worth an explanation

Comment: @lioness99a,the numerator is minus,so the denominator should be minus to be the fraction positive